# npm cluster package on a server cluster

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

So I have an app I am working on and I am wondering if I am doing it correctly.

I am running `cluster` on my node.js app, here is a [link](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster) to `cluster`. I couldn't find anywhere that states if I should only run `cluster` on a single server or if it is okay to run it on a cluster of servers. If I continue down the road I am going I will have a cluster inside a cluster.

So that it is not just opinions as answers, here is my question. Was `cluster` the package made to do what I am doing (cluster of workers on a single server inside a cluster of servers)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you have a cluster inside a cluster ****!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cluster wasn't specifically designed for that, but there is nothing about it which would cause a problem. If you've designed your app to work with cluster, it's a good indication that your app will also scale across multiple servers. The main gotcha would be if you're doing anything stateful on the filesystem. For example, if a user uploads a photo and you store it on the server disk, that would be problematic when scaling out across multiple servers (that don't share the same disk).

Comment: Thanks, that was all I was wanting to know. I am not storing anything on the api server. I am using aws s3 and then storing the reference in mongodb.